# Connect Onion Omega2 to static ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, ip-address, onion-omega2

I can't get my [Onion Omega2](https://onion.io/store/omega2/) to connect to my ethernet via a static IP address and two DNS addresses. To connect my PC, I have to set the following:
IP address: `82.149.xxx.xxx`
subnet mask: `255.255.255.0`
gateway: `82.149.xxx.xxx`
DNS server: `212.xxx.xxx.xxx`, `83.xxx.xxx.xxx`

Which settings have to be made in `/etc/config/network` and possibly elsewhere?

I tried the following without success:

```
config interface 'wan'                
    option proto 'static'         
    option ifname 'eth0'       
    option ipaddr '82.149.xxx.xxx'  
    option netmask '255.255.255.0'
    option gateway '82.149.xxx.xxx'  
    list dns '83.xxx.xxx.xxx'    
    list dns '212.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given settings in `/etc/config/network` are correct. However, to apply the settings, it isn't sufficient to restart the network via `/etc/init.d/network restart` but also applying the DNS servers via `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq restart` which had not been done. After that, the Onion Omega2 is able to connect to the internet via its ethernet connection.